# Is there an iPhone application same like MS Office Suite?

Tags: iphone, ms-office

I am wondering if there is any iPhone application same like MS Office suite, I mean Spreadsheet, Word Processor and so on.

If you know a free app it will be better if not so what is the best pro payed one

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly MS Office but Apple has just released [Numbers](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id361304891?mt=8) (SpreadSheet), [Pages](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8) (Word Processor) and [Keynote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480?mt=8) (Presentations) for iPhone.

Each of them is priced $9.99